# Postgres: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying when query input parameter is null

Tags: postgresql

**Query:**

```
ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=AdditionalSupplementFields sql="SELECT * from AGX_ADDITIONAL_SUPP_FIELDS  WHERE
DB_COLUMN = ? AND FK_SUPP_FIELD_REC_ID = ?")

Call: SELECT * from AGX_ADDITIONAL_SUPP_FIELDS  WHERE DB_COLUMN = ADD_TEXT_FIELD_10 AND FK_SUPP_FIELD_REC_ID = null
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
```

**Exception:**

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 89
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT * from AGX_ADDITIONAL_SUPP_FIELDS  WHERE DB_COLUMN = ADD_TEXT_FIELD_10 AND FK_SUPP_FIELD_REC_ID = null
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=AdditionalSupplementFields sql="SELECT * from AGX_ADDITIONAL_SUPP_FIELDS  WHERE
DB_COLUMN = ? AND FK_SUPP_FIELD_REC_ID = ?")
```

I have tried below solution but it is not working:

```
SELECT * 
from AGX_ADDITIONAL_SUPP_FIELDS  
WHERE DB_COLUMN = ?1 
  AND FK_SUPP_FIELD_REC_ID = coalesce (?2,null)
```

Comment: try `FK_SUPP_FIELD_REC_ID = cast(?2 as bigint)` - but that won't return rows where `FK_SUPP_FIELD_REC_ID ` is null